# Gmail removes gradient from an email html body

Tags: html, css, gmail, gradient, amazon-ses

I'm using Amazon SES for sending emails and now I'm trying to create a template for the email "body". As the title says I'm using some gradients for a better view but the problem is gmail won't show them correctly.

I didn't paste all code, this is a simple example of how I'm using gradients

```
<html>
<head>     
    <style>
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .gradient {
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(121.12deg, #E83448 -8.32%, #C3356E 85.14%);
            background-clip: text;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: "Biennale-BlackIt";
            src: url("Biennale-BlackIt.otf");
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: "Biennale-Regular";
            src: url("Biennale-Regular.otf");
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 350px; height:700px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;">
        <div style="padding: 15px 45px 15px 45px;">
            <div style="margin-top: -10px;">
                <h1 class="gradient" style="font-size: 32px;
                    font-family: Biennale-BlackIt;">
                    Hello
                </h1>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxyPp.png)

This is how is should look [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLiMF.png)

How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

**Webkit** doesn't work in all browser try this:

```
       .gradient {
            background: linear-gradient(121.12deg, #E83448 -8.32%, #C3356E 85.14%);
            background-clip: text;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }
```

Comment: Same result, it's a bit wierd

Comment: Where are you using this code, I mean in a browser?